# Chrome execCommand 'insertHTML' inserts span outside of node when caret is inside it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, execcommand, inserthtml

My task is to insert an empty span node within a contentEditable div at current caret position.

The following gives me no problems on Firefox 22.0:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent" contentEditable=true>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
$('.parent').on("keyup", function(e){
    if (e.which == 73) {
       node = '<span class="new"></span>';
       document.execCommand('insertHtml', null, node);
   }
});
```

**To reproduce:** Place caret at some point of the word 'text', then press 'i' key to insert an empty span at current selection.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/amirisnino/pZecx/2/

**Example:**

When pressing 'i' key in the middle of the word

**Expected result:**

```html
<div class="parent" contentEditable=true>
    <div>tei<span class="new"></span>xt</div>
</div>
```

**What happens instead?**

```html
<div class="parent" contentEditable=true>
    <div>teixt</div>
    <span class="new"></span>
    <div><br></div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the contenteditable attribute of span element as false. In order to achieve your expectation, you have to move the last two lines outside of the if-condition. Here it is:

```
$('.parent').on("keyup", function(e){
    if (e.which == 73) {
         node = '<span contenteditable="false" class="new"></span>';
         document.execCommand('insertHtml', null, node);
       }
       content = $(this).html()
       $('.result').text(content)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$('.parent div').append(node);
```

instead of this:

```
document.execCommand('insertHtml', null, node);
```